# Playa inside matrix dynamically reload singles select list in safecracker form

Tags: safecracker, playa, dynamic

I'm using playa inside a matrix form in safecracker to add ingredients into my recipe list. If the ingredient isn't listed as an entry already, I've added a modal window that allows you to add a new ingredient listing. When the modal closes, I would like the playa field to refresh so that the new ingredient is displayed.

However, I'm having no such luck. It appears that playa has a dynamic element to it with the search function. It also appears that when I modify the html on scrollpane in firebug, I can only add a new item 'if' I have added it already using my modal. I was wondering whether there was a simpler function or callback I can use to refresh the whole list when my modal closes.

Comment: Hey Pete - it would help everyone if you'd add context to your post: show your work, what have you tried so far?  Have a look at the EESE Meta FAQ for some guidelines - those are there to help you get answers. :)  http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: +1. Some screenshots would be helpful. Also code excerpts (not your whole template, just the important/useful bits like the JS you are using). You need to make your question as easy as possible for people to answer, and statements like "It appears that playa has a dynamic element to it" aren't very helpful.